# Dowloading beginning of file preferentially in a torrent?

Tags: bittorrent

When downloading a video file sometimes I want to check the quality of the file, or whether subtitles are present or not, before downloading the whole file. In a direct HTTP download, I could run the temporary file and check this. Is there any way I can instruct a torrent client to download X% of a file before the rest of the file?

PS: I use utorrent as a client, but if something is possible in another client, then that's also acceptable.

Comment: That's what the sample files are for.. oh and stop using torrents the MPAA is watching you :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i believe it's possible to set download priority to the start and end of a file in utorrent. in the advanced preferences:

[image]

Comment: It helps, but it tries to download only 1 MB on each side, which is sometimes not enough for a preview.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the client. [Azureus/Vuze](http://azureus.sourceforge.net/) has a feature to prioritize downloading of first part of a file.